# how to record internet url's access in apache access log

Tags: apache, proxy, reverse-proxy

I had installed apache in my local computer. Now i wanted to make apache as a proxy for internet. The websites accessing by me need to recorded in the apache access log . Can you give me idea how can i make this ?